# Excel rounding to specific values

Tags: excel, rounding

I can't seem to find an excel function to round to a specific set of numbers.

I'm trying to work out a cell entry to round to one of the following numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 30, 60, 120, 180, 360, 1440, 2880, 4320, 5760, 7200, 8640 & 10080.

The number should round up or down to whichever value is closest.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [MROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427).

```
=MROUND($A1, 1)
=MROUND($A1, 2)
=MROUND($A1, 3)
=MROUND($A1, 4)
=MROUND($A1, 5)
=MROUND($A1, 10)
... etc.
```

[image]